# Creating Wordpress user pw in Registration Form

Tags: wordpress, user-account

I'm trying to let users create a Wordpress account inside of the civicrm registration form. I created the form and it shows the username field and it works no problem - I can see the account created in Civicrm and Wordpress.
But, there is no way for a user to create a password in the form. I saw that this may be intentional on a gitlab post. Is there a work around to this so the user can create a password by themselves in the civicrm registration form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was [intentional](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18982) for wordpress. The person needs to click the link in the email.

You can see the code that controls this in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/91ac1dc25c9e24422c6bc9feabca9e5c16b4856d/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php#L1034. It always returns FALSE.